# Word 2011 Envelope Mail Merge button is greyed out. Why

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, mail-merge, microsoft-word-2011

Steps to reproduce:

1. Launch Word
2. Create a New Document
3. Display the "Mail Merge Manager" from the Tools menu
4. Under "Select Document Type", click "Create New", select "Envelopes..."
5. Stare in disbelief at the greyed out "Mail Merge..." button sitting in the dialog you got from the "Mail Merge Manger"

For example, as seen here:
[image: Stupid Word Dialog]
What am I doing so wrong as to cause this maddening enigma?

I seem to be using version 14.3.0, on a Core i5 iMac running 10.8.2.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to print some envelopes, click the <kbd>OK</kbd> button and follow the steps in Mail Merge Manager.

Comment: Yeah, I've got that under control. Still curious about the answer to the question, though.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make Outlook for Mac the default application before it works. This can be done in outlook by going to preferences -> General -> Make default. Then restart Word and it should work.

Comment: Outlook doesn't exist on the Mac. This question shouldn't have anything to do with that, unless Microsoft is even dumber than I thought (and that's really saying something).

Comment: READ: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Outlook

Comment: Outlook doesn't exist on the mac?? Read first before you make nonsense statements

Comment: I stand corrected! But to be fair, there was NO Mac version of Outlook from 2001 to 2011, and it isn't included in the Home/Student edition. Do you mean to say that that button exists solely for a link to Outlook, which may or may not be installed? And if that's the case, does your answer refer to making Outlook the default email application, or something else?

Comment: (If you can clarify by editing your answer, I'll be happy to reverse my downvote.)

Comment: Editted the answer, it should work when you install Outlook. Maybe it works with the default mail program of OSX as well, but I think not.